# ラズパイでキーボード、マウスが全く効かない

Tags: raspberry-pi

ラズパイでキーボード、マウスが全く効かなくなってしまいました。効かなくなったというか、電力が供給されなくなりました。データの保存を行う前に効かなくなったので、できれば電源がついている状態でどうにかしたいです。
誰かこの状況を打開できる方法を教えて下さい。

確認していること

- HDMIは動作している
- USBポートはどこも効かない

やったこと

- 一旦全て抜いて一つずつ差す（HDMIも）

Comment: HDMI接続のディスプレイに正しく表示されているなら(power off でないなら), USBポートを OFFにした可能性があります。Ethernet 接続 もしくは Wi-Fiで接続できるかどうか, になるかも (あるいは UART有効にしてるなら, そちらでの接続)

Answer (score 0):

まずは、SDカードを交換してイチからOSを入れ直してみましょう。
それでキーボード／マウスが正常に動作する、というのであれば、ラズパイ自体の故障の可能性は排除することができるようになります。

ってことで、まずはそれをやってみて結果を報告するようにしましょう

Comment: 電源はどうすればいいですか？そのままぶち抜く感じでいいんですか。

Comment: 今の状態であればぶち抜くしかないでしょう。TELNETとかSSHで接続できるようになってるなら、そこから操作すればいいですが、そうなっていないようですし